# A semimartingale interpolation problem

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-approximation

This question is a direct extension of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395806/a-martingale-extension-interpolation-problem).

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ be a stochastic basis and let $N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $T>0$, $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^{N}$ be a partition of $[0,T]$ with $t_0=0,t_n<t_{n+1},t_N=T$.  Fix $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and suppose that for each $n=0,\dots,N$ we are given some
$$
X_{t_n}\in L^1_{\mathbb{P}}(\mathcal{F}_{t_n-},\mathbb{R}^k).
$$

Then, *(or when?)* can we find an $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$-adapted *semi-martingale* $(\hat{X}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with $\sup_{t\in [0,T]} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[\|\hat{X}_t\|^1]<\infty$ and with:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\hat{X}_{t_n}\in \cdot) =\mathbb{P}\left(X_{t_n}\in \cdot\right)\qquad \forall n=0,\dots,N
?
$$

Comment: How about $Z_t = X_{t_n}, t_n \le t < t_{n+1}$

Comment: Ah okay, so the only reason that there may be an issue finding such a semi-martingale in: "Remark 2.3 of OPTIMAL TRANSPORTATION UNDER CONTROLLED
STOCHASTIC DYNAMICS 1 By Xiaolu Tan and Nizar Touzi" is because the authors want absolutely continuous characteristics?